# Multiple WHERE clauses MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I was wondering if something like this was possible and how to do it?

```
SELECT *

FROM table

WHERE name='name'

WHERE user='user'
```

Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `AND` or `OR` if you want to specify multiple conditions.

```
SELECT *    
FROM table    
WHERE name='name'    
AND user='user'
```